# fullcalendar language

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как поменять язык  в fullcalendar ,если  нужного языка  нет  в locales?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1):

Вам необходимо загрузить js-файл данных на языке для того, чтобы использовать недоступные по умолчанию. эти файлы должны быть включены в директорию fullcalendar в catalog/lang. они должны быть объявлены с помощью тега  после загрузки главной библиотеки fullcalendar.

```
<script src = 'fullcalendar/fullcalendar.js'> </script>
<script src = 'fullcalendar/lang/es.js'> </script>
<script>
  $ (function () {
    $ ( '# Календарь'). FullCalendar ({
    });
  });
</script>
```

Перейдите по этой ссылке https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/lang, там есть подробная инструкция по смене языка